# lua_pcall error message is missing

Tags: lua, torch

I'm using `lua_pcall` to call some function and I want to catch the error.
In some cases, the error seem to get lost. How can that happen?
This is for both the case where I use an error handler and when I don't use not. In both cases, the top of the stack is not a string.

The C code:

```
  lua_getglobal(L, "debug");
  lua_getfield(L, -1, "traceback");
  lua_replace(L, -2);
  lua_rawgeti(L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX, my_func_index);
  // now push n_in number of values on the stack
  luaT_stackdump(L);
  int pcall_ret = lua_pcall(L, n_in, n_out, -n_in - 2);
  // lua_pcall will consume n_in+1 values from the stack.
  if(pcall_ret != 0) {
    const char* errmsg = lua_tostring(L, -1);
    if(!errmsg) {
      errmsg = "(No Lua error message.)";
      printf("Unexpected Lua stack:\n");
      luaT_stackdump(L);
    }
    printf("Lua error code %i: %s\n", pcall_ret, errmsg);
    lua_pop(L, 2);  // remove error and debug.traceback from the stack
    return ...;
  }
  // now we got n_out values on the stack
```

The Lua function which is called looks like this (for testing):

```
    function (x, W, b, index)
        print "hi from Lua func"
        A = torch.rand(15, 12)
        B = torch.rand(12, 23)
        C = torch.dot(A, B)
    end
```

It somehow gets an error when it calls `torch.dot`.
But I don't exactly know why. And I don't get any meaningful error.
This is what my question is about.

The output:

```
  1. Lua object type: function
  2. Lua object type: function
  3. userdata 4165a368 [torch.FloatTensor]
  4. userdata 4165a390 [torch.FloatTensor]
  5. userdata 4165a230 [torch.FloatTensor]
  6. userdata 4165a258 [torch.CharTensor]
---------------------------------------------
hi from Lua func
Unexpected Lua stack:
  1. Lua object type: function
  2. userdata 40ea1230 [torch.DoubleTensor]
---------------------------------------------
Lua error code 2: (No Lua error message.)
```

Or maybe my code is correct and it really should return the error string here? So maybe there is some memory corruption when calling `torch.dot`, i.e. something gets messed up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I need to call `torch.updateerrorhandlers()`. Then I get some meaningful output:

```
hi from Lua func
Lua error code 2: inconsistent tensor size at /tmp/luarocks_torch-scm-1-1092/torch7/lib/TH/generic/THTensorMath.c:384
stack traceback:
        [C]: at 0x7f63cd831360
        [C]: in function 'dot'
        [string "return ..."]:9: in function <[string "return ..."]:2>
```

But only if I have `torch.updateerrorhandlers()` inside the Lua function.

I tried with this C code and that doesn't work:

```
    lua_getglobal(L, "torch");
    lua_getfield(L, -1, "updateerrorhandlers");
    lua_replace(L, -2);
    assert(lua_pcall(L, 0, 0, 0) == 0);
```

I figured out that if I do another `torch.updateerrorhandlers()` call right before my actual `my_func_index` `lua_pcall`, it works.
This is unexpected but maybe this is because this might be another thread
(which I would not have expected).
Actually, I found in the Torch code the function `torch.updatethreadlocals()` which is exactly for this purpose and I'm calling this one now, right before my other `lua_pcall`:

```
    lua_getglobal(L, "torch");
    lua_getfield(L, -1, "updatethreadlocals");
    lua_replace(L, -2);
    assert(lua_pcall(L, 0, 0, 0) == 0);
```

This works now.